# Unable to call WebApi 2 method

Tags: asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-mvc-routing, url-routing

I've added a webapi 2 controller to my project, inside api > LoginAPi as shown here:

[image]

Inside LoginApi I have the following:

```
[RoutePrefix("api/LoginApi")]
public class LoginApi : ApiController
{
    // GET api/<controller>/5
    public string Get(int id)
    {
        return "value";
    }

}
```

Inside my global.asax file I have:

```
public class WebApiApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
    }
}
```

Inside App_Start I have the following:

```
 public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        // Web API configuration and services

        // Web API routes
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
```

I then put a break point inside the Get method within LoginAPI and run the project and type the following into the URL:

```
http://localhost:37495/api/LoginApi/4
```

But I get : 
`No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'http://localhost:37495/api/LoginApi/4'.`

So I thought OK let me specify the method name as so

```
http://localhost:37495/api/LoginApi/Get/4
```

This returns: 
`The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.`

Now I've been looking at this for a while so maybe I've missed something obvious, but if someone can please tell me what I'm doing wrong I'd very much appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `routeTemplate` you have set up would work for convention-based routing except for the fact that Web API adds the string "Controller" when searching for the controller class (as per [this article](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/routing-in-aspnet-web-api)). You therefore need to rename your controller class `LoginApiController` in order for the convention-based routing to work.

For attribute-based routing, the addition of the `RoutePrefix` attribute should be combined with a `Route` attribute on your action. Try adding the following to your `Get` method in your controller:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("{id}")]
```

And then navigate to `http://localhost:37495/api/LoginApi/4`.